# Error when setting up pm2 startup script with yarn

Tags: ubuntu, yarnpkg, ubuntu-18.04, pm2, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to use the startup-script from PM2 in combination with yarn on my ubuntu server.

The way I start the ecosystem.config is the following:
`yarn pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --name backend`

I get the status online.

In the next step I run:
yarn pm2 startup systemd
=> `sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /home/ubuntu/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u ubuntu --hp /home/ubuntu`
But in addition I get the error: error Command failed with exit code 1.

I'm guessing that the part `/home/ubuntu/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2`is pointing to the wrong path because when I run:
which pm2 => `/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/pm2`

The command:
`sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u ubuntu --hp /home/ubuntu`

returns the expected response:

```
[PM2] Init System found: systemd
Platform systemd
Template
[Unit]
Description=PM2 process manager
Documentation=https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Environment=PATH=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/home/ubuntu/.pm2
PIDFile=/home/ubuntu/.pm2/pm2.pid
Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Target path
/etc/systemd/system/pm2-ubuntu.service
Command list
[ 'systemctl enable pm2-ubuntu' ]
[PM2] Writing init configuration in /etc/systemd/system/pm2-ubuntu.service
[PM2] Making script booting at startup...
[PM2] [-] Executing: systemctl enable pm2-ubuntu...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pm2-ubuntu.service → /etc/systemd/system/pm2-ubuntu.service.
[PM2] [v] Command successfully executed.
+---------------------------------------+
[PM2] Freeze a process list on reboot via:
$ pm2 save

[PM2] Remove init script via:
$ pm2 unstartup systemd
```

After that I run: `yarn pm2 save`

Now I'm rebooting the system and I a expecting to have the status=online after the startup. But I get the information that the status is stopped.
The logs show the following issue:

```
0|yarn  | /bin/bash: /tmp/yarn--1688570524918-0.5051360360690733/yarn: No such file or directory
PM2     | App [yarn:0] exited with code [127] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2     | App [yarn:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2     | App [yarn:0] online
0|yarn  | /bin/bash: /tmp/yarn--1688570524918-0.5051360360690733/yarn: No such file or directory
PM2     | App [yarn:0] exited with code [127] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2     | App [yarn:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2     | App [yarn:0] online
0|yarn  | /bin/bash: /tmp/yarn--1688570524918-0.5051360360690733/yarn: No such file or directory
PM2     | App [yarn:0] exited with code [127] via signal [SIGINT]
```

I am suspecting that the `sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /home/ubuntu/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u ubuntu --hp /home/ubuntu` is still missing information for the startup script. Has anyone the same issue or can help how to fix it?